# Pulling docker image python:2.7-onbuild taking a long time

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to implement a [GitLab CI](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/) pipeline with the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: python:2.7-onbuild

services:
  - rethinkdb:latest

test_job:
  script:
    - pytest
```

The `requirements.txt` in the same directory contains a single line `pytest==3.0.7`.

The problem is the "Pulling docker image python:2.7-onbuild" seems to be taking a long time; over 14 minutes (see screenshot below).

[image]

Is this normal? Is there perhaps a faster way to set up the testing?

Comment: Pulling a container shouldnt take 14 minutes. What happens when you reproduce the pulling (or entire CI job) by hand on the machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have only occurred the first time, when it took 61 minutes. After that, the pipelines ran in about a minute.

(For reference, the `CI-test` repository is at https://gitlab.com/khpeek/CI-test with all pipelines succeeded, after some modifications).